# For loop in macro works when I step through but get run-time error '91' when I try to run it

Tags: vba, excel

I have set up a macro to go through a list of unique identifiers, take these to a website, and return a value into the adjacent cell. I have had some success with it working, but it has been very intermittent, it has also gone though part of the list and then broke. I can step into the VBA and it will work for the entire list, but when I run it the macro will fail, usually with

> Run-time error '91': object variable or with block variable not set

Here is my code with details changed for privacy:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Autofill()

Dim i As Integer
Dim FinalRow As Integer
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To FinalRow

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "https://website" & Cells(i, 1).Value & "last part of url"
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Dim zDD As String
    zDD = Trim(Doc.getElementById("NameValue").innerText)
    Cells(i, 2).Value = zDD
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & "@company.com"
    IE.Quit
    'Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM# "tried this with varying times to see if it would help, did not have any success"
    Set IE = Nothing


Next i


End Sub
```

Any ideas on why it will run stepping through and not running the macro? Could it be related to my use of internet explorer?

Comment: Please don't call your sub Autofill. Avoid words which are functions or methods. Use a different descriptive title. And change those Integers to Long to avoid potential overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Doc.getElementById("NameValue")` needs more time - Have another `Do Loop` until `Doc.getElementById("NameValue")` returns an object

Try this (untested):

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoFillFromIE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long, IE As InternetExplorerMedium, docElement As Object

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False

    For i = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        IE.Navigate "https://website" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & "last part of url"

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        IE.Refresh

        Do
            Set docElement = IE.Document.getElementById("NameValue")
            DoEvents
        Loop Until Not docElement Is Nothing

        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value2 = Trim$(docElement.innerText)
        ws.Cells(i, 3).Value2 = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & "@company.com"

        Set docElement = Nothing
    Next i

    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks great, its running without throwing an error but will only put the unique identifier from the first "i" into the rest of the cells unless I step into. Could this be a timing issue? possibly not finishing the first cell before going to the next? It does fill all the cells, but with the value retrieved from the website using the first id.

Comment: I made an edit related to browser caching - can you try again

Comment: This works stepping through but not when running the macro. It gets "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Comment: I added `IE.Refresh` before the `Next i` command in your original answer and it is working now. It is fairly slow but I don't think that can be helped due to the time it takes to load IE. Thank you so much for the help! This is my first time asking a question on here, is there something I need to do when it has been resolved?

Comment: Glad it helped. I rolled back to the previous version and added `IE.Refresh` as well. If it resolved the issue you can [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it, so others can reference it if they have the same problem (you can also upvote it if it was helpful as well)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Cells` method, specify what sheet you're refering to. Example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(.....
```

If you do not use this and call the macro from another sheet, Excel will try to use `Cells` method with the active sheet and you will get your error.